# How to create AWS Lambda layer for Shapely 2.0 (Python3.9)?

Tags: linux, aws-lambda, shapely, amazon-linux-2, geos

I've been trying to create a layer for Lambda that would allow me to use shapely for runtime python 3.9. For some reason lambda just keeps returning the error:
`lambda_function': No module named 'shapely.lib`

So there's probably something wrong with my .zip file. Ive installed in path `shapely.zip/python/..`

Here's what Ive done so far:

1. Looked for dependencies and ended up zipping up together in a python3 venv: shapely, geos, pyproj and numpy like this:

   `mkdir python`
   `python3 -m venv env`
   `source env/bin/activate`
   `cd python`
   `pip3 install shapely -t python`
   `pip3 install geos -t python`
   `pip3 install numpy -t python`
   `pip3 install pyproj -t python`
   `zip -r shapely.zip python`

I also tried `pip install shapely`, but that returned `Nothing to do`.

2. Tried altinstalling python 3.9 on an ec2 (with amazon linux 2) and running it in virtual environment, but the ec2 keeps telling me that python3.9 is an unknown command. Ive had to fight with layers before but this seems to be the most notorious so far.
3. I also noticed that by running "pip3 install geos", I it probably installed a wrong version, so I tried to install a tar.bz2 for geos 3.9 and install it like with what I found from the internet:

   `wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.9.0.tar.bz2`
   `tar xvfj geos-3.9.0.tar.bz2`
   `cd geos-3.9.0`
   `./configure`
   `make`
   `sudo make install`

But that gave me this weird error:

```
`/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 '/bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /bin/install -c   libgeos.la 
'/usr/local/lib'`    
`libtool: install: 'libgeos.la' is not a valid libtool archive'`  
`libtool: install: Try 'libtool --help --mode=install' for more 
information.`  
`make[4]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1`  
`make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/python/python/geos-3.9.0/src'`  
`make[3]: *** [install-am] Error 2`  
`make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/python/python/geos-3.9.0/src'`  
`make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1`  
`make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/python/python/geos-3.9.0/src'`  
`make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1`  
`make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/python/python/geos-3.9.0'`  
`make: *** [install] Error 2`
```

4. I even found a suggestion from the libgeos website to install it via

   `sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras`
   `sudo amazon-linux-extras enable epel`
   `sudo yum search geos`
   `sudo yum install geos geos-devel`

but that returned that there was nothing to install from the extras that would be "geos" or "geos-devel".

Has anyone successfully created one or got any suggestions I could try?

Comment: Solved this using my other non-ec2 VM with python 3.10 and then decided to change my lambda to 3.10 as well since this worked.
`Path for python.zip = python/lib/python3.9/site-packages`    

Then just installed normally within a venv:

`python3 -m venv env `  
`source env/bin/activate`  
`mkdir python/lib/python3.9/site-packages`  
`cd python/lib/python3.9/site-packages`  
`pip install shapely -t .`  
`cd .. to folder before python folder`  
`zip -r python.zip python`  

The path that works for ie. requests didnt. (``requests.zip/python/libraries_installed_here``)

Comment: Hi, it's better to write a regular answer; comments are not suitable

Answer (score 0):

Solved this using my other non-ec2 VM with python 3.10 and then decided to change my lambda to 3.10 as well since this worked.
`Path for python.zip = python/lib/python3.9/site-packages`

Then just installed normally within a venv:

```
python3 -m venv env  
source env/bin/activate
mkdir python/lib/python3.9/site-packages 
cd python/lib/python3.9/site-packages  

pip install shapely -t .  

cd .. to folder before python folder  
zip -r python.zip python
```

The path that works for ie. requests didnt work for some reason. (`requests.zip/python/libraries_installed_here`). Seems like the required dependencies are already inside also (duh), even though separate would be good too.